# Issue with std::atomic and custom structs

Tags: c++, struct, atomic, stdatomic

Can't seem to do this (see code) for some reason. Looked at documentation, there doesn't seem to be a reason for this not to work...

```
struct vector {
    float x, y, z;
};
std::atomic<vector> Name = {0};
```

It says I can't initialize it with an initializer list, and when I go to use it in my code, it says it has no members.

```
Name.x = 4.f;
Name.y = 2.f * Name.x;
Name.z = 0.1f;
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's `Name._My_val.x, Name._My_val.y, Name._My_val.z` not `Name.x, Name.y, Name.z`

Why it is no one told me this is beyond me, but whatever.

Comment: No, it's not. What you're doing here is playing with an internal implementation detail. It will not function as you intend.

Comment: You're bypassing the memory fence. These operations will not be atomic.

Comment: Do you want a struct with separate atomic members, or do you want the whole struct to act as a single atomic object?  Anyway, this only compiles on MSVC, where a 12-byte struct is not lock-free, so this will break the atomicity of other atomic operations.  https://godbolt.org/g/ji6ABT **It doesn't even compile on other compilers.**

Comment: @RichardHodges: It's bypassing the *lock*.  Ordering and atomicity are separate things; you can have atomicity without any fencing (e.g. with `memory_order_relaxed`).  Technically a store to `Name._My_val.x` will be atomic on x86, because it will be naturally-aligned.  But doing anything with multiple members, or reading and then write, is also definitely not atomic.  And even a plain store breaks the atomicity of *other* RMW ops by ignore the lock, as you point out.

Comment: Guys, I only use it to read, I still store with `Name.store();` The operation I'm specifically doing is storing to another vector a multiple of the current "Name" vector.

Comment: Then each load will be separately atomic, but you won't get an atomic snapshot of the entire struct.  Thus you'll break the atomicity of `Name.store()` in other threads by peeking at the internals while the lock is potentially held.  If that's not something you care about, then use a struct with separate atomic members.

Comment: `struct vector {
    std::atomic<float> x, y, z;
};` like this?

Comment: If you _really_ want to atomically  access the whole struct, and your workload is dominated by reads, look into userspace RCU, or seqlocks.

Comment: @vidsac: yes.  Use that with `foo.x.store(value, std::memory_order_release)` or whatever if you don't need sequential consistency.  But keep in mind that there won't be any consistency between `x` and `y`.  Reading and writing them separately means you could get an `x` value that came from a different writer than the `y` value.

Answer (score 4):

An instance of `std::atomic<vector>` isn't an instance of `vector`. It doesn't have `x`, `y`, or `z` as members. What it does have (conceptually, internally) is an instance of `vector`. But you can't access it with the `.` operator because that would break atomicity, which is, like, the point of `std::atomic`. (This is also why you can't use an initializer list.)

To access the `vector` stuff, use `load()` and `store()`:

```
//atomically load a snapshot of Name
auto name_snapshot = Name.load(); //name_snapshot is a vector instance
name_snapshot.x = 4.f;
name_snapshot.y = 2.f * name_snapshot.x;
name_snapshot.z = 0.1f;
//now atomically store it:
Name.store(name_snapshot);
```

Comment: Good `.load()` and `.store` example.  Probably a good idea to point out isn't it isn't an atomic RMW; you'd have to use a CAS loop for that.  It's only an atomic load and a later unconditional atomic store which could step on updates from other threads.

Comment: Also, the only problem with the initializer is missing a level of braces: `std::atomic<vector> Name = {{0,0,0}};` compiles just fine (https://godbolt.org/g/o5PdVF), and so would other ways of having `atomic<T>` forward args from its [(non-atomic) constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/atomic) to the `T()` constructor, like `std::atomic<vector> Name2{{1.0,1.0,2.0}};`

Comment: could I, in turn, do something like this? `Name.store({0, 0, 0})` or would I need to make an actual variable?

Comment: @vidsac: yeah, you can make an anonymous temporary with `vector({0,0,0})`, so you can do `Name.store(vector({0,0,0}), std::memory_order_relaxed);`.   See https://godbolt.org/g/bXXn1t

Comment: Does this lock the struct such that other threads cannot access it?

Answer (score 2):

There is documentation for `std::atomic<>` here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

There are no members x, y, and z on a `std::atomic<>`.

`std::atomic<X>` is a type in which the *entire* X can be replaced atomically, not individual parts of it.

What you probably want is a mutex, since for a structure like `name_snapshot`, std::atomic will use a mutex in any case. Since there is unlikely to be an atomic instruction available handle an atomic load/store of the entire structure.

Comment: On some compilers, for example gcc or clang targeting x86-64, `atomic<T>` is lock-free for T up to 16 bytes.  It has to use `lock cmpxchg16b` even for `.load()` or `.store()`, though, so it's not very efficient.  (And for this reason, gcc7 and later returns false for `.is_lock_free()`, and doesn't inline the `lock cmpxchg16b`, but instead always calls a library function.  https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2017-01/msg02344.html.  Even though the current library implementation is lock-free, and can't be changed without breaking compatibility with code that inlines `lock cmpxchg16b`)